# How to search for an unknown collection containing identifying document fields?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to search for an unknown collection that contains a document with identifying fields like an email?

My structure is like this:

Each user gets their own collection based on a unique ID. Each collection contains a user doc and a accounts doc. User doc contains the information about the user that I would like to search for. Accounts doc contains a collection of bank accounts that I want to transfer money between users.

My problem is that I don't want users to type in the long unique id to enter the collection but to type the email of the user that is inside the collection\user document. The email is unique.

Have I just made a bad structure for my project or is there something I can do?

[image: My Structure] 

**UPDATE** 
Thanks, [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5246885/alex-mamo) and [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) for the feedback. 
I went on and changed my structure to as shown:
`/users/$uid/accounts/$accountid`.
 
Did a `java Query collectionReference = db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("uEmail", userEmail);` and saving the `document.getId()` as a `String userId`.

I Then use the `UserId` in a `spinner` to enable the user to pick an account from the `userId` accounts collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alex said, there is no way to load data from a collection (with the client-side SDKs) unless you know the collection name.

But in this case, it seems like your collections are named after the user's UID.

That means that if the user is signed in, you can know their collection by:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
CollectionReference userCollection = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(uid);
```

A few notes:

- It is much more idiomatic to store your structure with a top-level collection of `users`, and then a document for each user under that, and then subcollections for the other data under *that*. So for example: `/users/$uid/accounts/$accountid`.
- The server-side SDKs *do* have a method to get a list of collections, for example like this [`listCollections` method in the Node.js SDK](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/1.3.x/Firestore#listCollections). But these SDKs are only to be used in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions, and not directly on the client. Even with this SDK though, you'll have to iterate the list of collections and check each in turn, because as said before: you can only read data from a collection of which you know the name.
- If you're trying to look up the collection/UID for another user than the one who's signed in to the app, you may need to way to map an email address to a UID. Such functionality is not available in the client-side SDKs. But similar as the point above, there is a method [`getUserByEmail` in the Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUserByEmail).

Comment: Always going deeper than my answers 

Comment: Thanks for the compliment Alex, although I'd wholeheartedly disagree with the "always" in that statement. :)

Comment: Thank you for that, puf :) I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to search for an unknown collection that contains a document with identifying fields like an email?

No, you should know the name of your collection in order to be able to use it in your reference. There are **no** wildcards in Cloud Firestore paths to collections/documents. You have to identify every collection and every document by their specific ids.

Comment: Could I use a spinner that selected all my collections and displayed the user email as text, and whatever the user selected the spinner could get the collection/document path?

Comment: Yes you can, but this means that once you get all your collections and select a particular one, you should make another request to get the desired data.